# How does ASP.Net Identity validate reset password token?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, token, reset-password

Can somebody please help me in understanding how ASP.NET Identity validates the token for the resetting of password. What are the criteria that makes a token invalid? I can't find an article that elaborates this topic in detail.

Thank you very much !

Comment: em.. criteria is simple - validated token must be the same as generated token. Unless you are asking a different question...